# Filtering block data in Excel by rows ( weather forecast data from National Weather Service)

Tags: excel, sorting, block, weather, forecasting

I need to get data for weather forecasts for a period of several years for 18 US cities. I can obtain the data from the National Weather Services but the problem is that the Excel file contains data for all US cities and the data is presented in blocks. I got the data in uncompressed format from here: http://www.mdl.nws.noaa.gov/~mos/archives/mex.html. For example, here is the data for January 2006: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lf552bgbwdyusli/01.2006.xlsx. I need only information about min and max temperature for 18 particular cities, which means I need only the first 5 rows of data for each city. The data cannot be sorted by columns and cannot be transposed as it contains text cells.
I was wondering whether there is a faster way to select the data I need than searching for each particular city and copy and pasting the data in a new worksheet. This method would be fine if I had only a couple of files of data, but I have around 100 of them.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Copying data is the only way to copy the data ... how you do it is completely different question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you have any suggestions of how it can be done quicker?

Comment: Which Excel version do you have?